# How do i make Websphere App redirect each applications log entry to different file?

Tags: java, logging, websphere

I am using the normal `java.util.logging` to log .  Is it possible to redirect each applications log to a different file?

Example :

```
Application.war 's log entries to Application.log 

Application2.war 's log entries to Application2.log
```

and so on ,

Not a logging expert , or would it better to just filter the ones corresponding to the app and try to automate it with script - just a thought ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

opted for log4j , went through its doc and found out that i can configure in the log4j.xml to redirect each apps to a different file as required (and to sysout so that i can see in RAD)

Doesn't seem possible with simple java.util.logging , but can't verify it

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible.

Please take a look at the following;

http://wpcertification.blogspot.co.uk/2008/10/using-logproperties-file.html

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wchelp/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.commerce.admin.doc%2Ftasks%2Ftlslogging.htm

Do take a look at this thread as well.

[Websphere Application Debug logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310604/websphere-application-debug-logging)

Comment: Actually i wanted to send log from each application to a different log file. The one you mentioned would work only for separating portal and WAS logs but still i cannot separate each portlets logs .
I want each log to go to a different log file

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use one application with one log. You only need to add one logging configuration file for one application. See this [sample](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=143) to learn java logging.

Comment: Thanks,but since all of websphere server apps are run under the same java process so is only one log file possible for the all the applications?